# Different Icon per feature with Leaflet Ajax

Tags: leaflet, ajax

How can I have a circle marker or one of a selection of icons depending on a feature's properties using LeafletAjax?

https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

```
function pointToLayer(feature, latlng){
  console.log(feature.properties.shape);
}

var features = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/features.json?circuit=555",{
    pointToLayer: pointToLayer,

    onEachFeature:onEachFeature,

    style: function (feature) {
      return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
    },
});
```

I've started to try to build this, but Point to layer is only called once.  The console log shows just the first feature's shape.

I have also tried to add the code to the onEachFeature function:

```
function onEachFeature(feature,layer){
    if (feature.properties.shape == 'point'){
    feature.marker =  L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    });
  }else if(feature.properties.shape == 'tree'){
    feature.marker =  L.marker(latlng, {icon: treeIcon});
  }

  if (feature.properties){
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties['popup_content']);
  }
}
```

Which doesn't work - I have made up the "feature.marker =" bit.

How do I set the marker?

Comment: In `pointToLayer`, what happens if you insert `return L.marker(latlng);` into the function? What is the result?

Comment: I get a marker for each Point in the geojson.  Which led to other discoveries, and  boom I got it working. Turns out, the bug was elsewhere.  Not in the PointToLayer bit.  Thanks for the nudge @Stefan_Fairphone

Comment: Could you post a working example as an answer to your question? This will help others that have the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, I declare the icons and then just choose it based on a feature's properties.

```
function pointToLayer(feature, latlng){
    if (feature.properties.shape == 'point'){
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: markerIcon});
    }else if(feature.properties.shape == 'tree'){
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: treeIcon});
    }else if(feature.properties.shape == 'hazard'){
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: hazardIcon});
    }else if(feature.properties.shape == 'log_pile'){
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: logPileIcon});
    }else{
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: labelIcon});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify [@Will](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/105984/will)'s answer using a [switch-case statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
function pointToLayer(feature, latlng){
    var icon
    switch (feature.properties.shape) {
        case 'point':   icon = markerIcon; break;
        case 'tree':    icon = treeIcon; break;
        case 'hazard':  icon = hazardIcon; break;
        case 'log_pile':icon = logPileIcon; break;
        default:        icon = labelIcon;
    }
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon})
}
```